# Signature Draw for phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Sorry for asking this again but i didn't find the simple signature plugins in phonegap. I want to capture the signature for my phonegap application so i prepare to use this one  [link](http://www.tricedesigns.com/2011/12/21/capturing-user-signatures-in-mobile-applications/) but it is not worked in phonegap but workrd in browsers please suggest any plugins or how to develop capture signaute in my phonegap application.

Comment: No one can help unless you share some code what you tried and what issue u get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to just use some JQuery or JavaScript which can allow to draw signature & save your time to write your own code.

[Check this](http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/#require-drawn) Might be it will helpful to you.

Answer (score 4):

I have done this signature capture using above [Chintankethiya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1562548/chintan-khetiya) answer but I spend nearly one and half days to do this one in Phonegap. So here i put the sample of what I have done. It will be more helpfull for newcomers like me.

First you need to download the `1. jquery.signaturepad.css`, `2.jquery.signaturepad.js` and `3.json2.min.js` from the [Github link](https://github.com/thomasjbradley/signature-pad/) and implement the signature applicationn.

index.html:

```
 <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title></title>
 <link href="jquery.signaturepad.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.signaturepad.js"></script>



</head>

<body>

 <form method="post" action="" class="sigPad">
    <label for="name">Print your name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="name">
    <p class="typeItDesc">Review your signature</p>
    <p class="drawItDesc">Draw your signature</p>
    <ul class="sigNav">
      <li class="typeIt"><a href="#type-it" >Type It</a></li>
      <li class="drawIt"><a href="#draw-it" class="current" >Draw It</a></li>
      <li class="clearButton"><a href="#clear">Clear</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="sig sigWrapper">
      <div class="typed"></div>
      <canvas class="pad" width="198" height="55" id="sigmy"></canvas>
      <input type="hidden" name="output" class="output">
    </div>
    <div><input type="button" value="Create" id="mysign" onclick="setImage();"></div>
    <button type="submit">I accept the terms of this agreement.</button>
     <img  width="198" height="55" id="sigmy1">
  </form>

  <script src="jquery.signaturepad.js"></script>
  <script>
   var a;
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.sigPad').signaturePad();
    });
    function setImage() {
    var a = $("#sigmy")[0];
    var b= a.toDataURL();
    document.getElementById("sigmy1").src=b;

    }
  </script>
  <script src="json2.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Refer this one](http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/#require-drawn)

Don't forget to `include cordova.js` and `library and xml`. We can do multiple signature also and filter either Draw or Print using this plugin. That's all the Signature app will be ready. Feel free to ask any doubts.

Comment: Canvas is coming(both browser and device) but unfortunately it does not draw anything. May be i missed something in `libray` and `xml`. Could you please refer me to some documentation where i can use them appropriately. Secondly; i tried to run `cordova plugin add https://github.com/thomasjbradley/signature-pad.git`; but ended up with error `Either there is a connection problem or plugin spec is incorrect: CordovaError: Cannot find plugin.xml for plugin '1444043036559'. Please try adding it again`. I am sure there is no connection problem :).

Requesting a little help please!!